# ImageMagick command line: converting PDF to high definition images

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a PDF file to images on the fly using imagemagick from command line. These PDFs are in very high definition and I would like to get correlated images (JPG).

Usually used Gimp, when I convert these PDF to 600dpi under this software the quality is super top. But I do not see myself convert more than 500 images one by one with Gimp ... that's why I turn to ImageMagick, especially since converting image files on the fly happens to me more and more often, I would like to master this type of tool.

Alas, with ImageMagick, by default I get very small images (type 468x705), despite the setting of a density at 600dpi:

```
convert *.pdf -density 600 -quality 100 *.jpg
```

So I added a `resize` command (I also tried `scale`), the image is much higher definition (type 4680x7050), but is pixelated as if I had remained at the default definition:

```
convert *.pdf -resize 1000% -density 600 -quality 100 *.jpg
```

I even thought it could come from the order of orders, but that does not change anything:

```
convert *.pdf -density 600 -resize 1000% -quality 100 *.jpg
```

An idea ?

Subsidiary (but less crucial) question: how to keep the same name for the destination file as the original one?

EDIT : In addition to the for loop proposed by Mark Setchell I just discovered that you can use `mogrify`. Example:

`mogrify -format jpg -density 600 -blur 1x1 -quality 100 *.pdf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want something like this - note that you put the `-density` **before** the PDF filename:

```
for f in *.pdf; do convert -density 144 "$f" "${f%pdf}jpg"; done
```

The tricky part is removing the `pdf` extension and replacing it with `jpg`, I used *"bash Parameter Substitution"* which is pretty well described [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

---

In long-hand, that is

```
for f in *.pdf; do 
   convert -density 144 "$f" "${f%pdf}jpg"
done
```

---

Another option is with `mogrify`:

```
mogrify -density 144 -format jpg *pdf
```

---

If you have **GNU Parallel** installed, you can do it more readably and faster like this:

```
parallel convert -density 144 {} {.}.jpg ::: *pdf
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So I found a setting quite similar to that of Gimp by adding `-blur 1x1`

Comment: I had to use mogrify with -density 600 -blur 1x1 -quality 100 options to get a good quality output. The flags listed in this answer were not enough.